# ASP.Net Application Context Data Sharing

Tags: asp.net, caching, security

I have several websites that use a HTTPModule (wrapped in a dll) to authenticate users and store an authentication object in the application cache for ~10 hours. I then set a cookie containing the cache key on the users machine.

I'm now looking for a way to allow admins to clear a specific cache object for all websites for any given user (effectively logging them out) causing them to automatically log back in (via windows authentication) next time they visit any of the sites.

I was planning to have a single administration website with the facility to reset logins - but I can't change the application cache for other websites for obvious security reasons.

Is there any way of passing a signal to those sites that use the authentication module so that they can clear their own application cache?

Note: I have read up on memcached but I would like to avoid a solution that isn't 'Standard ASP.NET' if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ideas:

- If they are on the same server, you could have a file containing the active logins in the file system, that all projects can access.
- Add a generic handler to each project, that resets the login of a given user. Call this from another project when he gets logged out there. You could add a passphrase for security reasons.

**EDIT:** I just thought of a better solution:

- Create a central "authentication" project that keeps track of the login status. Call it from the websites (e.g. through generic handlers, webservice, ...) to log out a user or check his status.

Comment: I'm leaning towards a form of generic handler by analysing requests in HttpApplication.BeginRequest & running the cache clear code if the url matches some criteria. It does mean maintaining a central list of URLs for each website in order to call it though.

Comment: True, but you will have a need for this list with every kind of solution, where you want to have direct communication between the websites. I just thought of another, possibly better way though, will edit it into my answer.

Comment: I already have a central site that manages this, however it passes permissions of authenticated users back to the requesting project so that they can be cached. If I were to cache this data in the central project it would defeat the objective as consuming projects would continually need to query to central authentication site to obtain user permissions. I think im in a "Cache22" situation, har har.

Answer (score 0):

I've opted to piggyback code onto the existing HTTPModule.

I check for a custom user-agent string, if it exists I clear the relevant cache entries based on a query string and return a custom HTTP header upon success.

The only extra overhead is checking the user-agent for each request which I can live with.

With this setup I can now use a `WebRequest` object (injecting my custom user-agent string) from my central site to send messages to all sites using the module.